# Using Python and opencv on a cluster without graphical interface (ImportError: libXdmcp.so.6)

Tags: python, opencv

I am using Python+Tensorflow for CNN training on a high performance computing cluster. I need opencv (cv2) for some data augmentation and preprocessing stuff. The nodes where I execute my python code do not have a graphical interface. However, cv2 in python wants to load a file that is not available without a graphical interface, it is part of the X Display Manager Control Protocol library.

```
import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: libXdmcp.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas how I can get this to work? I got this to work on several stand-alone machines which have a graphical interface.

All the machines in the cluster are using Red Hat Linux. I'm using Python3.5 with Anaconda3. My ultimate goal is to use the imgaug package (https://github.com/aleju/imgaug) which requires cv2. I installed opencv using opencv-python (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python). I do not have admin access, therefore I can barely install system related stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by installing libXdmcp:

```
yum install libXdmcp -y
```

Or:

```
apt install libXdmcp -y
```

Depending on your cluster's OS.

Also, since you mentioned a computational cluster, if you are using common tools for computation like Jupyter or Zeppelin, you can use ! or %sh to run bash commands within the notebook itself.